# Bottle (python): post decorator is not working

Tags: python, bottle

I was following this tutorial http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html

Route works well, I haven't tried in route decorator GET and POST parameters, because I found more elegant way in that tutorial.
I uses get and post decorators, but on post I had an error - 405, method is not allowed. Why? How should I fix it?

```
import os

# setup global and environ variables
app_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__name__))
os.environ['FAMILY_BUDGET_ROOT'] = app_root

from bottle import route, run, redirect, request, get, post, static_file
from controller import check_login, get_page


# static section

@route('/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def stylesheets(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root=app_root)

# dynamic section

@route('<path:path>')
def family_budget(path):
    redirect('/family_budget/login')

@get('/family_budget/login')
def login():
    username = request.get_cookie("account", secret='very_secret_key')
    if username:
        redirect('/family_budget/main_page')
    else:
        login_page = get_page('templates/login_page.html')
        return login_page

@post('/family_budget/login')
def do_login():
    username = request.forms.get('username')
    password = request.forms.get('password')
    if check_login(username, password):
        request.set_cookie("account", username, secret='very_secret_key')
        redirect('/family_budget/main_page')
    else:
        return "<p>Login failed.</p>"


run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request to POST route must be HTTP POST - for example from a `<form action="/family_budget/login" method="post">` on a web page. If you just enter the URL in browser, the request will be HTTP GET instead of POST, which is what is error 405 saying.

Comment: Is it not enough to make "submit" button in form with "post" method?

Comment: Button has no "method" attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)